# Angular: Is a factory's private variable a consequence of javascript closures

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using angular for a little bit now. Lately private variables belonging to factories have been bothering me. I was wondering how these variables are kept after the factory is created.

In other words, if I have the following code:

```
angular.factory('Factory', [function () {
var privateVar = 'private';
var publicVar = 'public';
return publicVar;
}])
```

I was wondering how privateVar 'stays alive' so to speak after the initial function is called. I went back and started reading about the fundementals of Javascript and ran across closures. I thought closures might be the answer to my question. I haven't completely pieced it together though.

So my question is: 
In the example why does privateVar get stored? If publicVar was a function then I would understand why privateVar got stored, namely closures. But, in this case, where publicVar is an Object, I am not sure what is keeping privateVar from being garbage collected.

Comment: In this case `privateVar` is elligible for garbage collection, as no references to it "escape" the factory function. If `publicVar` was an object however, and one of its methods referenced the `privateVar`, then a reference would actually "escape" and the private variable would be kept alive through the closure.

Comment: privateVar will be garbage collected. What makes you think it won't be?

Comment: @WayneEllery See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers, why does the apiToken's secret variable not get garbage collected.

Comment: @WayneEllery never mind, I guess there the secret IS garbage collected. I suppose I always saw something like: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/understanding-service-types/ and thought that if you declare a variable in a factory it is always a private variable. Now I see that it is only a "private variable" if there is a public facing function that references it.